# Compiling a JNI application in VC++ for 64-bit on 32-bit Windows

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit

I am building an application that has to use a Java library, but needs to produce a CLR DLL, so I'm using JNI.

The DLL compiles fine for 32 bit, but produces a linker error for 64:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" long __cdecl JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J0YAJPEAPEAUJavaVM_@@PEAPEAXPEAX@Z)

I figure the problem lies in jvm.lib, since not having it in library path produces the same error for 32bit. Is jvm.lib architecture specific? I saw someone having the opposite problem (compiled for 64, got similar error for 32) and he solved it by installing the 32bit JDK. However, trying to install the 64bit JDK on my 32bit machine throws an "invalid win32 application" error.

Any ideas how to get this to compile?

Comment: Yes, a .lib file is architecture specific.  You really ought to get a x64 version of the OS, if not to install the JRE then at least to test your code.

Comment: How I finally got it to compile was just grabbing the x64 jvm.lib from a 64-bit machine, that had the JDK installed.